# How to convert datetime to yyymmdd format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting date in following format

```
20.04.2013 09:33:34
```

I want to make it as `2013.04.20 09:33:34`

Any ideas how to do this using javascript or jquery?

Comment: [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is my personal fav.

Comment: @MikeChristensen can you show  me how? I have already downloaded date.js

Comment: Did you read the docs?  What did you try?  Date.js already seems to parse that format natively, so it should be pretty easy.

Comment: Well someone is voting down every single answer, but try something like: `var date = Date.parse('20.04.2013 09:33:34');  var formatted = date.toString('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss');`

Comment: @MikeChristensen when i do Date.parse and pass date then i get Nan

Answer (score 1):

Split by a space or period. Then take the appropriate sections and combine them together like so:

```
var s = "20.04.2013 09:33:34".split(/[ .]/)
console.log(s[2] + '.' + s[1] + '.' + s[0] + ' ' + s[3]);
```

No need for any external libraries or to load it into a `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
var date = moment("20.04.2013 09:33:34", "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss");
date.format("YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss")
// "2013.04.20 09:33:34"
```

Comment: I think someone came along and downvoted all the answers in this question (including the ones that were deleted)

Comment: Yea, I was gonna post a date.js version but decided against it.

Answer (score -1):

Need to do this

```
var date = "20.04.2013 09:33:34".split(/[ .]/);
var newData = date[2] + "." + date[1] + "." + date[0] + " " + date[3];
console.log(newData); // Outputs: "2013.04.20 09:33:34"
```

Comment: Why this answer has a downvote?